# Error with imports after packaging using setup tools

Tags: pip, python-3.6, setuptools, egg

I am trying to package my project as a library in python using setup tools. Being my first time, I arranged my project in the following directory. Importing the package from its parent directory does not cause any errors and is working fine. But when I install it using setup tools and try to import from a general directory, I'm getting an Import error for importing files inside the packa
The directory structure is as follows:

```
    driver_scoring
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config.py
│   ├── processing
│   │   ├── data_management.py
│   │   ├── scoring_components.py
│   │   └── validation.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── pipeline.py
│   ├── predict.py
│   ├── train_pipeline.py
│   └── VERSION
├── MANIFEST.in
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

And in my **init**.py file, I have included the following code:

```
import os

from driver_scoring.config import config

with open(os.path.join(config.PACKAGE_ROOT, 'VERSION')) as version_file:
    __version__ = version_file.read().strip()
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 from driver_scoring.config import config
      4 
      5 with open(os.path.join(config.PACKAGE_ROOT, 'VERSION')) as version_file:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'driver_scoring.config'
```

And my setup.py is as follows:

```
NAME = 'driver_scoring'
DESCRIPTION = ''
URL = ''
EMAIL = ''
AUTHOR = 'Nevin Baiju'
REQUIRES_PYTHON = '>=3.6.0'

def list_reqs(fname='requirements.txt'):
    with open(fname) as fd:
        return fd.read().splitlines()

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

try:
    with io.open(os.path.join(here, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
        long_description = '\n' + f.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    long_description = DESCRIPTION

ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
PACKAGE_DIR = ROOT_DIR / NAME
about = {}
with open(PACKAGE_DIR / 'VERSION') as f:
    _version = f.read().strip()
    about['__version__'] = _version

setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=about['__version__'],
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author=AUTHOR,
    author_email=EMAIL,
    python_requires=REQUIRES_PYTHON,
    url=URL,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests',)),
    package_data={'driver_scoring': ['VERSION']},
    install_requires=list_reqs(),
    extras_require={},
    include_package_data=True,
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy'
    ],
)
```

I am not getting any errors when I try to import it from the project's parent directory and I am able to run the project as desired. However, when I try to install and import the project from the installed directory, I am getting the import error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by myself. I had forgotten to add the **init**.py file in the config folder and that is what caused the import errors.